# Automorphism group of the group $(\mathbb{R}^n,+)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, infinite-groups

As a vector space, it is clear that the automorphism group of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\mathsf{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$.

My question is: What is the $\text{Aut}((\mathbb{R}^n,+))$ ($n \ge 2$) as a group? Clearly, $\text{Aut}((\mathbb{R}^n,+))$ contains $\mathsf{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Given that the [automorphism group of $\mathbb{R}$ is enormous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation), to simplify matters, I would greatly appreciate an answer with respect to continuous automorphisms (if this is known).

The question above is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1516265/map-closed-under-addition-but-not-multiplication) concerning additive maps that do not preserve scalar multiplication. In particular, are there continuous isomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n \ge 2$) that do not preserve scalar multiplication? (Clearly, this would indicate that the containment above is strict.)

Comment: By unique divisibility of $\Bbb{R}^n$ any endomorphism of abelian groups is $\Bbb{Q}$-linear. Because $\Bbb{Q}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$ won't this quickly lead to the conclusion that a continuous endomorphism of abelian groups is necessarily $\Bbb{R}$-linear?

Comment: There are noncontinuous maps that satisfy the desired property. I agree with jyrki's comment once you require continuity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Continuous homomorphisms are adressed in @JyrkiLahtonen's comment, so I'll adress non-continuous ones.

Note that $\Bbb R$ is a $\mathfrak{c}$-dimensional $\Bbb Q$ vector space. ($\mathfrak{c}$ is the cardinality of $\Bbb R$)

So as $\Bbb Q$-vector spaces and in particular as groups we have:

$\Bbb R^n \cong \left(\Bbb Q^{(\mathfrak{c})}\right)^n \cong \Bbb Q^{(n\mathfrak{c})} \cong \Bbb{Q}^{(\mathfrak{c})} \cong \Bbb R$
(This isomorphism is not continuous!)

Thus $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb R^n) \cong \operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb R)$, which is adressed in the linked wikipedia page.

Note that this also illustrates how large $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb R)$ is: it contains a copy of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb R)$ for every $n\in \Bbb N$.

Answer (score 6):

The set of continuous automorphisms of $\mathbb R^n$ is $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$.

To see this assume $f\colon\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is an additive homomorphism, i.e. $f(u + v) = f(u) + f(v)$ and $f(0) = 0$, but we know nothing about whether it respects scalar multiplication.  If $n \geq 0$ is an integer then $f(nu) = nf(u)$ because multiplication by $n$ is repeated addition and $f$ respects addition.  If $n \leq 0$ is an integer then $f(nu) = -f(-nu) = -(-n)f(u) = nf(u)$.  So $f$ respects scalars from $\mathbb Z$.  Now $nf\left(\frac{1}{n}u\right) = f\left(n\frac{1}{n}u\right) = f(u)$ so multiply both sides by $\frac{1}{n}$ to get $f\left(\frac{1}{n}u\right) = \frac{1}{n}f(u)$.  Since $f$ already respects $\mathbb Z$ we get now that $f$ is $\mathbb Q$-linear.

None of this used continuous so far.  The automorphism group of $\mathbb R^n$ is $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb Q}(\mathbb R^n)$.  If we ask that $f$ be continuous and $r$ is a real number then take rationals $a_i$ such that $a_i \to r$ as $i \to \infty$.  We have $a_if(u) = f(a_iu)$.  Taking the limit as $i \to \infty$ on both sides (and using that $f$ is continuous to pass this limit to the inside of $f$) we get $rf(u) = f(ru)$.  So if $f$ is continuous then $f$ is $\mathbb R$-linear.